# If I push an object in space with 1N, will accelerate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, free-body-diagram

I'm trying to self study Classical Mechanics and I got a question on it.

Assuming that an object (I will call it Alex and weights 1kg) is in space and there are no objects except Alex and there is no external force. So if I push Alex with a force of 1N for 10 seconds and then stop pushing, he will move with a constant velocity or accelerate in time? Newton's first law says that an object will go with constant velocity if there are no forces that act on it, but I know that second Law says that for a constant mass, force=ma, so if I push with 1N will accelerate?  :)

Comment: If you like one of the answers, you can "pay" the author my accepting the answer.

Comment: @garyp, true, but one should wait at least 24 hours to give people in every timezone in the world a chance to respond.

Comment: @RayButterworth Good advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

He will accelerate only till the force is acting on it in accordance to Newton's Second Law. It will reach a velocity due to that acceleration and then continue with that constant velocity according to the Newton's First Law.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that would be like that, but I wanted to know if I'm right

Answer (score 0):

The body will be moving with a constant velocity which is the velocity the body had at the moment the force was removed and it will be 10 m/sec.

The moment the force is removed , the body continues with the speed gained at the last moments. If the force was not removed and acted continuously the body would have been accelerating all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

According to the second Newton law body in the end will achieve speed :
$$ v = v_o +  \frac 1m \int_{0~\text{sec}}^{10~\text{sec}} F(t)dt $$
Not necessary force should be constant,- it can vary with time in the same time window it is integrated. If object was already traveling with initial speed $v_o$, until you started to push it, then you will boost it's speed once again to bigger value. Not necessary force direction must be same as initial speed vector. Force can act for example in reverse direction - opposite to that of object initial speed. In such case you will start to **slowdown** object by very amount of opposite momentum given.